# Combining submit action with navigation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to build a multiple choice quiz in Ruby on Rails, but although I've got it sort of working I still want to improve my navigation.

As it currently stands I have two buttons: One for submitting the quiz_guess (which is an attribute of Answer) and another for selecting the next :question. I would like to combine these two buttons into a single one so I don't have to first update the attributes and then select the next question.

How do you go about doing that?

My questions controller:

```
  def quiz_guess
    @survey = Survey.first
    Answer.update(params[:answers].keys, params[:answers].values)
    if @survey.save
      flash[:notice] = "Guess saved successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'show_quiz', :id => @survey.next, :survey_id => @survey.id)
    else
      render 'show'
    end  
  end

  def show_quiz
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id]) #answer
    @answers = Answer.where(:survey_id => @survey.id)
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @questions = Question.where(:survey_id => @survey.id)
    @surveys = Survey.all
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  end
```

My show_quiz view:

```
     <%= form_tag quiz_guess_questions_path, :method => :put do %>
       <% for question in @survey.questions do %>
          <li><%= question.content %></li>
             <% for answer in question.answers do %>
               <li>
                 <%= fields_for "answers[]", answer do |f| %>
                   <%= answer.content %>  
                   <%= f.check_box :guess, :checked => false %>    
                 <% end %>
                </li>
             <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <%= submit_tag "Guess" %>
     <% end %>

    <%= link_to t('.back', :default => t("helpers.links.back")), surveys_path, :survey_id => @survey.id, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
    <%= link_to t('Previous question', :default => t("helpers.links.previous")), {:action => 'show', :id => @survey.previous, :survey_id => @survey.id}, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
    <%= link_to t('Next question', :default => t("helpers.links.next")), {:action => 'show', :id => @survey.next, :survey_id => @survey.id}, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
```

My model:

```
def next
    Survey.limit(1).order("id ASC").where("id > ?", id).first
end

def previous
    Survey.limit(1).order("id DESC").where("id < ?", id).last
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to improve your `next`(and `previous`) functions. First, you don't need to have `limit(1)` while you have `.first` or `.last` at the end. `.first` and `.last` each guarantees only 1 record to be returned.

Problem is when you call `@survey.next` on your last record, it will point to nothing. Here you have two options. First, you can use a check, and if `next` returns `nil`, disable the next button.

Second, make the order cyclic. Clicking `next` on the last survey takes to the first survey, and vice verse. Here's how:

```
def next
  Survey.order("id ASC").where("id > ?", id).first || Survey.first
end

def previous
  Survey.order("id DESC").where("id < ?", id).last || Survey.last
end
```

Comment: I appreciate your comments. The problem that I have is that I'm calling @survey = Survey.first in the quiz_guess action so it will always go back to the first record. If I write `@survey = Survey.find(params[:id])` it will give me a RecordNotFound error - couldn't find record with 'id' =

Comment: Could you please do `return render json: params` as the first line in your method, and can check what actually the params you are receiving?

Comment: `{"answers":{"1":{"guess":"0"},"2":{"guess":"1"},"3":{"guess":"0"},"4":{"guess":"1"}},"commit":"Guess","utf8":"✓","_method":"put","authenticity_token":"W3j3HnqgsCT+5E3XcmmZ0gU/Xj/V0btscAmG/BBPT0TU9DnsHI8gOsgWyVYpm10KRJiHeyreCczPLR5IOd3vXQ==","controller":"questions","action":"quiz_guess"}`

Comment: @ljnissen Obviously, you are not receiving `id` in your `params`. Something is wrong.

Comment: It's probably because I've nested my models such that Survey has_many :questions and Question has_many :answers. As you say, something is wrong.